# What other justifications are there for using id's sparingly?

Tags: html, css, client-side

While I don't need convincing that `id` selectors should be used sparingly and that `class` selectors should be used primarily for applying CSS , I'm having trouble explaining it to members of my group project. When we met as a group to go over everyone's HTML and CSS files, I noticed they used `id` selectors for almost everything(including elements that weren't unique). While I explained that `id` selectors should be used to style very unique elements only in CSS and `class` selectors should be used for applying CSS to everything else due to their re-usability, now I'm trying to remember other reasons. So my question is what other reasons are there for using `class` selectors over `id` selectors for non-unique elements?

Comment: Do you mean that your classmates are primarily using id selectors instead of class selectors for applying CSS?  Or that they are giving every element an id attribute?

Comment: @JohnGordon sorry for the confusion, I meant to say they're using id selectors instead of class selectors for applying CSS. Will edit the question for more clarification.

Comment: Personally, I feel the reason you gave is enough. Adding a large number of id selectors just isn't good style, and quickly becomes unwieldy. Especially if you cant to make changes, it is quite difficult to ensure you changed everything you wanted to.

Comment: Some thoughts on this issue "[Don’t use IDs in CSS selectors?](http://oli.jp/2011/ids/)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, the uniqueness of `id`s is reason enough to not use them as selectors, but there are more:

An element can have several `class`es, but only one `id`. You might want to same element to be both a `.news-article` and `.breaking-news`. If you use JavaScript you can have one class for styling (`.unstyled-list`) and another for your script (`.side-menu`). That way you can change your list to `.roman-numerals` without breaking your script.

What makes `id`s even worse for applying styles is the combination of their uniqueness and their higher [specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/). If you use `id`s for styling you will surely get stuck in a specificity race (especially if you need to maintain the CSS over time, which is probably the case).